# Implementing a R code in C

Tags: c, r

I use R and I implemented a Monte Carlo simulation in R which takes long time because of the for loops. Then I realized that I can do the for loops in C, using R API. So I generate my vectors, matrices in R then I call functions from C(which will do the for loops) and finally I present my results in R. However, I only know the basics of C and I cannot figure how to transform some functions to C. For instance I start with a function in R like this:

```
t=sample(1:(P*Q), size=1)
```

How can I do this in C? Also I have an expression in R:

```
A.q=phi[,which(q==1)]
```

How can I use "which" expression in C?

Comment: Hello neticin, Stack Overflow is not a code translation service. Start implementing those in C, and when you get stuck implementing something specific you can ask about that here. (I suspect neither of these functions are easily done in C.)

Comment: Have you profiled your code, before trying to optimize it? You may be trying to optimize parts of the code that are not slow...

Comment: Best is to read C language first, if you indeed want to interface your C code in R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you start writing C code, you would be better off rewriting your R code to make it run faster.  `sample` is vectorised.  Can you move the call to it outside the loop?  That should speed things up. Even better, can you get rid of the loop entirely?

Also, you don't need to use `which` when you are indexing.  R accepts logical vectors as indicies.  Compare:

```
A.q=phi[,which(q==1)]
A.q=phi[,q==1]
```

Finally, I recommend not calling your variables `t` or `q` since there are functions with those names.  Try giving your variables descriptive names instead - it will make your code more readable.